# Bootstrap 3 - align text to form-control items across grids

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the correct way in bootstrap to have proper alignment of inputs and labels across grids?

I would like to have the labels to be placed exactly the same as the first col.
See my plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jaMAp38Rr1g7BLW3R5AI

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" style="width:80px;">
        <label>OK</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>NOK</label>how to align it to the same as text 'OK'?
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Use `.form-control-static`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static)

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/0uVL2IIglzV0mrhqZdla?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" style="width:80px;"/>
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">OK</label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;">
    <p class="form-control-static"><b>NOK</b></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since bootstrap 4, this changed to

.form-control-static

CHANGED TO:

.form-control-plaintext

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#forms-1